# Htaccess Rewrite reverts to default .htaccess file

Tags: htaccess

I've a question about the `.htaccess` file...

I'm configuring a website and it all works fine, except when I change the `.htaccess` file. Every time I refresh the page, WordPress overwrites the default `.htaccess`:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

So all the directives that I put in `.htaccess` are lost because WordPress rewrites the file.

Why this is occurring?

May be a hack?

Answer (score 1):

manual modifications of .htaccess must be done after "# END WordPress" to not be overwrited

Comment: or before `# BEGIN WordPress`. putting it after probably won't work so well ;)